# convert BSTR to const char*

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Which is better code for converting BSTR parameters to ANSI in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576610/which-is-better-code-for-converting-bstr-parameters-to-ansi-in-c-c)
> [How to convert char * to BSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606075/how-to-convert-char-to-bstr)

How I can convert BSTR to const char*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `BSTR` is actually a `WCHAR*` with a length prefix. The `BSTR` value points to the beginning of the string, not to the length prefix (which is stored in the bytes just “before” the location pointed to by the `BSTR`).

In other words, you can treat a `BSTR` as though it is a `const WCHAR*`. No conversion necessary.

So your question is really: “How can I convert a Unicode string (`WCHAR*`) to a `char*`?” and the answer is to use the `::WideCharToMultiByte` API function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215963/how-do-you-properly-use-widechartomultibyte). Or, if you are using MFC/ATL in your application, use the [ATL and MFC Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

```
#include "comutil.h"

BSTR bstrVal;
_bstr_t interim(bstrVal, false);    
    // or use true to get original BSTR released through wrapper
const char* strValue((const char*) bstrVal);
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btdzb8eb.aspx) handles all the Wide Char to multibyte conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef OLECHAR FAR * BSTR;
typedef WCHAR  OLECHAR;
```

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx).

WCHAR*. It's a wide char, not a char. This means it's Unicode, not ASCII and shouldn't be converted. If you want to use const char*, don't use wide types.

Although, it is possible using some hackery, you'd possibly lose data as you'll be converting the text from Unicode to ASCII.

Comment: Narrow character strings do not have to be ASCII. They could be UTF-8 in which case you will still be able to display characters that are typically thought of as wide, e.g. Chinese and Japanese.

Comment: Some functions don't have an ASCII version. For instance the `Graphics::DrawString`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535991(VS.85).aspx