# When using W2A to convert BSTR to std::string, is there any clean up needed?

Tags: c++, com, bstr

Code looks like the following:

```
class A 
{
  public:
     std::string name;
};

A a;
CComBSTR textValue;
// some function which fills textValue
a.name = W2A(textValue);
```

Now, I've used CComBSTR so I don't have to dealloc the BString, but does W2A allocate any memory that I might have to deal with? i.e. should I have:

```
 char *tmp = W2A(textValue);
 a.name = tmp;
 // do something to deallocate tmp?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Be very cautious** with the W2A/A2W macros. They are implemented with "alloca" (dynamic allocation directly on the stack). In certain circumstances involving loop/recursion/long string, you will get a "**stackoverflow**" (no kidding).

The recommanded way is to use the "new" helpers templates. See [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx)

```
A a;
CComBSTR textValue;
// some function which fills textValue
CW2A pszValue( textValue );
a.name = pszValue;
```

The conversion use a regular "in stack" buffer of 128 bytes. If it's to small, the heap is automatically used. You can adjust the trade-off by using directly the template types

```
A a;
CComBSTR textValue;
// some function which fills textValue
CW2AEX<32> pszValue( textValue );
a.name = pszValue;
```

Don't worry: you just reduced your stack usage, but if 32 bytes is not enough, the heap will be used. As I said, it's a trade-off. If you don't mind, use `CW2A`.

In either case, no clean up to do:-)

Beware, when pszValue goes out of scope, any pending char* to the conversion may be pointing to junk. Be sure to read the "Example 3 Incorrect use of conversion macros." and "A Warning Regarding Temporary Class Instances" in the above link.

Comment: This mention of the "new" helpers is wonderful. I've been hoping to find something that won't overrun my stack, and this is it. Thank you thank you thank you! +1!

Comment: @MPW Thanks. You'r welcome. Don't forget: code for UNICODE all the way down, and many problems will disappear... :-)

Answer (score 4):

No cleanup is required because `W2A` [allocates memory on the stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx#atl30stringconversionmacros). There are certain memory-related pitfalls you have to be aware of (direct consequences of stack allocation), but nothing that looks immediately suspicious in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

No cleanup is required for the conversion; however, the original `BSTR` must be freed at some point with a call to [SysFreeString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysfreestring), unless you're using `CComBSTR`, which wraps the `BSTR` and takes care of freeing it.

If you expand the `W2A` macro, you'll see it calls the `wcslen()` function to determine the length of the passed in string.  It also calls the `AtlW2AHelper` method, which takes in a null-terminated wide string as a parameter.  Both of these functions will effectively limit the length of the converted string to the first null encountered.  If your BSTR does not contain embedded nulls in the middle of the string, then `W2A` should be fine.

The Microsoft article [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/87zae4a3(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) states:

> To convert from a BSTR, use COLE2[C]DestinationType[EX], such as
> COLE2T.

It also states:

> For OLE character string conversions, only COLE2T and CT2OLE (and
> COLE2CT, COLE2TEX, COLE2CTEX, CT2COLE, CT2OLEEX, and CT2COLEEX) are
> supported. For details, see atlconv.h.

But you cannot really stick to this suggestion of using OLE character string conversions to ANSI.  When the destination type is `T`, e.g. `COLE2T`, and `_UNICODE` is defined, then the conversion is as if the `T` were a `W` (wide character string).  The `COLE2A` macro is not defined in `AtlConv.h`, and `OLE2A` is equivalent to `W2A` in this header.  So you are still prevented from converting strings containing embedded nulls.

See Stack Overflow thread [Which is better code for converting BSTR parameters to ANSI in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576610/which-is-better-code-for-converting-bstr-parameters-to-ansi-in-c-c) for more discussion on this.

Or you could loop through the characters in source `BSTR` and convert each individual `wchar_t` to a `char` at the corresponding index position in your target `std::string`.  You'd again need to determine the `BSTR` string length beforehand by calling `SysStringLen()` on the `BSTR`.  You could preserve any embedded nulls within the middle of your string this way, but you'd have to handle the conversion of wide characters higher than 255 to something generic within the ANSI range.